# Where is code for `form_widget()` Twig function?

Tags: symfony, twig

I went looking to see how Symfony's extended Twig function `form_widget` actually works.  I was expecting to find the function in [symfony / src / Symfony / Bridge / Twig / Extension / FormExtension.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/FormExtension.php) . It's added to the function list there:

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(

...
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('form_widget', null, array('node_class' => 'Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Node\SearchAndRenderBlockNode', 'is_safe' => array('html'))),

...
    );
}
```

But no callable is listed (ie the 2nd arg is null). So what code is called when I use `form_widget(a_form_element)` in a Twig template?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Looking for it myself as a starting point for a table widget I want to create

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is a little late but I just happened to investigate the same question. This is what I found:

The code which is called when you use `form_widget()` is that produced directly by the `SearchAndRenderBlockNode` class when your template is compiled. The compiled template code then results in a call to `Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::searchAndRenderBlock()` where the proper Twig block is located, provided with context, and rendered.

Comment: Thank you for following up on an old question. It's really nice to finally understand how the "magic" works.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in `FrameworkBundle/Resources/views/Form/form_widget.html.php` or it equivalent in template `Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig`.

Comment: I'm not looking for the template code. I'm looking for the code that passes the form to the template code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the name space there.  Or that code.

Mine is in Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension.php

It uses Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Node\SearchAndRenderBlockNode

Comment: I've edited the link to point to the correct source, but the code in both places is the same.  In any event, `Twig_SimpleFunction`  takes 3 args: the first is the string that should be recognized as a function name in a Twig Template, the 2nd is the actual PHP function that is run, and the 3rd is an array of options to pass to the PHP function. `SearchAndRenderBlockNode` is an option. I want to know what PHP function gets called when I use `form_widget()` in a Twig template.

Answer (score 0):

This is now depreciated but here is available code directly using methods to render form when you call eg. form_row() twig function Here it is: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/Helper/FormHelper.php